# i have datetime column(hh:mm:ss ) format in dataframe.i want to pivot dataframe in which i want to use aggfunc on date column

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, python-datetime

I am trying to pivot dataframe given as below. I have datetime column(hh:mm:ss) format in dataframe. I want to pivot dataframe in which I want to use aggfunc on date column.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Type':['A', 'B', 'C', 'C'],'Name':['ab',  'ef','gh', 'ij'],'Time':['02:00:00', '03:02:00', '04:00:30','01:02:20']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print (df) 
pivot = (
    df.pivot_table(index=['Type'],values=['Time'], aggfunc='sum')
       )
```

| Type | Name | Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | ab | 02:00:00 |
| B | ef | 03:02:00 |
| C | gh | 04:00:30 |
| C | ij | 01:02:20 |

| Type | Time |
| --- | --- |
| C | 04:00:3001:02:20 |
| A | 02:00:00 |
| B | 03:02:00 |

I want C row should be addition of two time ; 05:02:50

Answer (score 0):

This looks more like [`groupby sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) than [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html).

1. Convert [to_timedelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) to have appropriate dtype for duration. (Makes mathmatical operations function as expected)
2. [groupby sum](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) on Type and Time to get the total duration per Type.

```
# Convert to TimeDelta (appropriate dtype)
df['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'])
new_df = df.groupby('Type')['Time'].sum().reset_index()
```

`new_df`:

```
  Type            Time
0    A 0 days 02:00:00
1    B 0 days 03:02:00
2    C 0 days 05:02:50
```

Optional convert back to string:

```
new_df['Time'] = new_df['Time'].dt.to_pytimedelta().astype(str)
```

`new_df`:

```
  Type     Time
0    A  2:00:00
1    B  3:02:00
2    C  5:02:50
```